# Uploading a csv file in PHP. Where is the error in the code

Tags: php, file-upload, csv, upload

```
<?php
    require '../config.php';
   // Edit upload location here   
   $result = 0;
   $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
   $path = csv;
   $ext = 'csv';
   $md5 = md5($name);
   $target_path = $path . '\\' . $md5 . '.' . $ext;

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
   }

   sleep(1);


?>
```

It won't upload any files such as with the file names that contain brackets, etc.

Comment: To show error messages, use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
```

Do:

```
$name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
```

you are getting the MD5 of $name so no reason to clean it as it will produce a 32-char hex string which will not contain any special characters regardless. If a filename contains special chars and you escape using the above the MD5 will completely change.

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely here:

```
$path = csv;
```

Here PHP is looking for a constant with name `csv` unless you have defined that, it is going to return null, so your `$target_path` is not being built correctly.

Comment: Hi, csv is defined to a directory with right permissions. Also, how can I get it to show any error messages. It is not even showing any error messages.

Comment: Why are you using `\\` in the `$target_path` definition.  Check to make sure you have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` set properly to where you can see PHP errors.

Comment: I also don't know why you are using `mysql_real_escape_string` here.  You are not inserting the filename into mysql so I don't know what you gain from this, though I don't think it is your problem unless you don't have a database connection open in which case it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just one more thing to try is use the pre defined DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR constant while building your $target path so...

```
$target_path = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . $md5 . '.' . $ext;
```

Comment: still not working. I am able to upload files without any special characters in the name

Comment: can you give me an example of one you are trying to upload that is failing?

Comment: What it sounds like is hapenning is you need to strip out any special characters from the file name that wouldn't be allowed when saving the file. For that, the long but safe approach is to create a function and inside that function define an array of characters that aren't allowed, then return str_replace($badchars, '', $target_path.